# Navigation Upgrade from Hydro to Indigo

Tags: navigation, ros-hydro, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have upgraded from Hydro and 12.04 to Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04. When I'm trying to compile the 2dNavigation package I had created for my robot, I get the following error message:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "move_base" with
  any of the following names:

    move_baseConfig.cmake
    move_base-config.cmake
```

I tried to run this command too:  `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-move-base`

but couldn't locate the package:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-move-base
```

This package is installed in Hydro.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195544/navigation-upgrade-from-hydro-to-indigo/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-21**:
The package looks like it's present in the repository. Are you sure you have your apt sources set up properly? (I've pruned my earlier comment about typos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks. You are right. I setup the source list again according to this: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu , and it worked

---

Originally posted by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) with karma: 651 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0